# Using variables in Complex MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My MySQL Query is like this :

```
 $myquery= "`SELECT  `year`, 

        sum(case when `countrycode` = '$countryone' then `values` else 0 end) AS `$countryone`,
        sum(case when `countrycode` = '$countrytwo' then `values` else 0 end) AS `$countrytwo`

FROM   `$index`
GROUP BY `year`";
```

This Query has to return all the values of the column values for two unique countrycodes in two different columns.

Before using the variables. my query was like this, which returned right output.

```
     $myquery = "SELECT  `year`, 

        sum(case when `countrycode` = 'NPL' then `values` else 0 end) AS `NPL`,
        sum(case when `countrycode` = 'USA' then `values` else 0 end) AS `USA`

FROM   `gainfinal`
GROUP BY `year`
";
```

But after replacing the real values with the variables the Query didn't work. How can I make the first Query run well ?

Comment: Use prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

Problem is this :

```
AS `$countryone`,
```

when you pass this in SQL query, `php` would try to search and replace a value for `$countryone`...so i would suggest to hardcode it as below :

```
$myquery= "`SELECT  `year`, 
        sum(case when `countrycode` = '$countryone' then `values` else 0 end) AS $countryone, /* notice "`" is removed */
        sum(case when `countrycode` = '$countrytwo' then `values` else 0 end) AS $countrytwo  /* notice "`" is removed */
FROM   `$index`
GROUP BY `year`";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It gave the right output but I nned to display the new column name as the value that has been passed in the variable.

Comment: @CivaBhusal : so `$countryone` has a value?

Comment: Yaa. $countryone has a value.

Comment: @CivaBhusal : try the updated query...just remove backtics from alias :)

Answer (score 1):

use - `'".$countryone."'` instead of  `'$countryone'` in the query as it will be treated as string.

Comment: @ SGT, Still, It didn't work for me. Should I change  AS `$countryone` to `".$countryone."' as well ? Or only change it and keep everything as it is.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the result into a JsonTable.  I changed the code as $temp[] = array('v' => $r['".$countryone."']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['".$countrytwo."']);      Did I use the correct format or I made a mess out of it ?

Comment: if u r getting it as an array then json_encode would do the all work to convert it to json.or else just built an array and pass it to json_encode.

Comment: @ SGT, Isn't it possible to pass a variable inside $temp[] = array('v' => $r['".$countryone."']); $temp[] = array('v' => $r['".$countrytwo."']);where $countryone and $countrytwo are variables. I need the values of $counntryone and $countryone but it prints $countrycode and $countryone.

Comment: My problem is actually with the variables inside above two lines.